# Atiyah-Macdonald 2.3

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In solving question 2.3 from Atiyah & Macdonald's commutative algebra textbook, I run into the following difficulty:

Let $A$ be a local ring with $k:= A/mA$ its residue field and let $M$ and $N$ be $A-$modules.

Note that for an arbitrary $A-$module $P$, we can view $P \otimes_A k$ as a $k-$ module by letting $\lambda (p \otimes_A x) = (p \otimes_A \lambda x),$ for $p \in P$ and $\lambda, x \in k.$

I want to show that $(M \otimes_A k) \otimes_k (N \otimes_A k) \approx (M \otimes_A N) \otimes_A k,$ where $\approx$ denotes an isomorphism.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Giving you an isomorphism is not very enlightning.

Comment: I tried constructing a map from $(M \otimes_A k) \times (N \otimes_A k) \to (M \otimes_A N) \otimes_A k$ and showing that it is multilinear. This would then imply the existence of an isomorphism by the tensor product defining property.

Comment: Did you solve exercise 2.15 on page 27? Once you solve it, the problem here becomes an immediate application of the exercise and proposition 2.14.

Comment: Is that really viewing $P$ as a $k$-module? Seems like it is treating $P\otimes k$ as a $k$-module.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Yes. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh: Thanks for the tip. I've actually just written up a solution to 2.15, although I'm not entirely sure that it's correct.  I will post it as another question because the two answers below seem to implicitly use this result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is associativity of the tensor product: as $A$-modules, $(M \otimes_A k) \otimes_k (N \otimes_A k) \cong M \otimes_A (k \otimes_k N) \otimes_A k \cong M \otimes_A N \otimes_A k \cong (M \otimes_A N) \otimes_A k$

Comment: Of course you also use the cancellation law.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Indeed (for reference, $k \otimes_k N \cong N$ as $A$-modules)

Comment: @zcn How $N$ can be seen as a $k$-module? In order to construct the tensor space $k⊗_kN$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When $A$-modules $M,N$ have the property that $\mathcal mM=\mathcal mN=0$ then $M\otimes_A N \cong M\otimes_k N$ as $A$-modules.