# Atiyah-McDonald Exercise 2.3

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I would like to point out that this question has a satisfactory answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877839/atiyah-macdonald-2-3). I am just trying a slightly different way.

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $P$. Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules. Let $k=R/P$. Let $M\otimes_R N=0$

We have 
$$(M\otimes_R k)\otimes_R(N\otimes_R k)\cong M\otimes_R(k\otimes_R(N\otimes_R k))$$
$$\cong M\otimes_R(k\otimes_R(k\otimes_R N))$$
$$\cong M\otimes_R((k\otimes_Rk)\otimes_R N))$$
$$\cong M\otimes_R( N\otimes_R(k\otimes_Rk))$$
$$\cong M\otimes_R( N\otimes_R(k\otimes_Rk))$$
$$\cong (M\otimes_RN)\otimes_R(k\otimes_Rk))$$
$$\cong (M\otimes_RN)\otimes_R(R/P\otimes_RR/P))$$
$$\cong (M\otimes_RN)\otimes_R(R/P)$$

For the last step we are using the fact that for ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ we have
$$R/I\otimes_R R/J\cong R/(I+J)$$

Since $M\otimes_R N=0$ we conclude that 
$$(M\otimes_R k)\otimes_R(N\otimes_R k)=0$$

My questioin:

Can we conclude from $(M\otimes_R k)\otimes_R(N\otimes_R k)=0$ that either $(M\otimes_R k)=0$ or $(N\otimes_R k)=0$?

Comment: what is the exercise?

Comment: Dimension is multiplicative across tensor product, for vector spaces (so yes!).